# How to make a container of a shape given below in flutter with height = 130 and width = 300

Tags: flutter, dart

How to make a container having shape like the image shown below.

width = 300 and height = 130

The Two semicircles should be aligned at centre of the height of container

Please click on "Card" to see image
[image: Card]

Comment: easier way is (if the background doesn't change) to screenshot that curved section and then put that image there with `Align` and `Stack` widgets. Hard way is to use `CustomPianter`.  Also update the title of the question, the title currently is not clear.

Comment: Use either `CustomPainter` or `CustomDecoration`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use custom clippers.

Here's an example on that,

```
class CardClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final Path path = Path();

    path.lineTo(0.0, size.height / 2 - 4);
    path.relativeArcToPoint(const Offset(0, 30),
        radius: const Radius.circular(10.0), largeArc: true);
    path.lineTo(0.0, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height / 2 + 26);
    path.arcToPoint(Offset(size.width, size.height / 2 - 4),
        radius: const Radius.circular(10.0), clockwise: true);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    path.lineTo(0.0, 0.0);
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => true;
}
```

Okay, that's about the clipper, we can now use it, but it won't provide us with shadow.

To cast shadows to clipper objects, we'll use [Clip Shadow package](https://pub.dev/packages/clip_shadow).

Now, we'll implement `CardClipper` with actual `Clip` Widget, in this case, `ClipShadow`,

```
ClipShadow(
  clipper: CardClipper(),
  boxShadow: [
      BoxShadow(
        offset: Offset(0, 4),
        blurRadius: 18,
        color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.1)),
  ],
  child: Card(...)
);
```

Try playing with values in the clipper until you get the desired output.

Comment: Hey Thanks for the solution, Please help me to align two semicircles at the centre of height of container

Answer (score 1):

You can try with custom painter.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  DateTime date = DateTime.now();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white54,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          child: Center(
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.green,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
              ),

                height: 100,
                width: 200,
                child: Stack(
                  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                  children: [
                    Positioned(
                        left: -15,
                        bottom: 35,
                        child: Container(
                          height: 30,
                          width: 30,
                          child: CustomPaint(
                            painter: MyPainter(),
                          ),
                        )),
                    Positioned(
                      right: -15,
                      bottom: 30.5,
                      child: Container(
                        height: 30,
                        width: 35,
                        child: CustomPaint(
                          painter: MyPainter(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                )),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()..color = Colors.white;
    canvas.drawArc(
      Rect.fromCenter(
        center: Offset(size.height / 2, size.width / 2),
        height: size.height,
        width: size.width,
      ),
      math.pi * 2,
      math.pi * 2,
      true,
      paint,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

output:

[image]

N.B: Adjust your color and circle height and width as you need

Comment: This is simple there is no need to use a package like  a Clip `Shadow package.` or others